# What is the source for the view that the Third Temple will be built by G-d and transported intact to Jerusalem?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, messiah, latid-lavo-future

I understand that there is a tradition that the Third Temple, may it come swiftly, will be built in Heaven and delivered intact to Jerusalem by G-d when the Messiah comes.  What is the source for this view?

Answer (score 5):

Per [this article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/148182/jewish/Who-Will-Build-the-Third-Bais-Hamikdash-Man-or-G-d.htm), this is based on Rashi, [whose source](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/148182/jewish/Who-Will-Build-the-Third-Bais-Hamikdash-Man-or-G-d.htm#footnote4a148182) is Midrash Tanchuma, Pekudei, sec. 11.

Answer (score 4):

A few of the sources are:

[Zohar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14249&st=&pgnum=619&hilite=) based on Chagai 2:9 גָּדוֹל יִהְיֶה כְּבוֹד הַבַּיִת הַזֶּה הָאַחֲרוֹן, מִן-הָרִאשׁוֹן says that the third Bais haMikdash will be built by Hashem.

[Yalkut Shimoni Tehilim 848](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9758&st=&pgnum=262) on Tehilim 93:5 עֵדֹתֶיךָ, נֶאֶמְנוּ מְאֹד--לְבֵיתְךָ נַאֲוָה-קֹדֶשׁ: ה', לְאֹרֶךְ יָמִים explains that when the house of Hashem will be built by Hashem then it will last forever.

Answer (score -1):

Look in Tanach with commentaries -- Yechezkiel chapters 40-48. Pretty explicit.

Comment: To give a full answer, you should summarize why this would give an answer to the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel to give a full comment, you should summarize why you are even here