# Can we get the Beis Hamikdash up and running by Yom Kippur?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, yom-kippur, korban

The rebuilding of the 3rd בית המקדש seems to be rather ambiguous. Especially, often with phrases like ‘Moshiach will come today (or tomorrow!)!’ And then that being equated with the immediate building of the בית המקדש.

With that, what type of miracles are to be expected with the building of the 3rd בית המקדש? Is there always a time when it can suddenly plop into existence, and be working without a hiccup, like it once was? Or is there going to be a startup sequence, in which there may not be enough time by tomorrow (which is the day before Yom Kippur) for everything to be up and running smoothly for the Yom Kippur Temple service -?-

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65130/3 And related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36165/3

Comment: One thought - You would need seven days after the preparation of the red heifer to purify those involved - or use tumah hutra betzibur.

Comment: The sheer amount of organization that goes into setting up the Beis Hamikdash for Yom Tov is scary.  Just look at any shul's Yamim Noraim committee, increase the number of people by a couple orders of magnitude, and add in the fact that nobody has practical experience with the operational side of things, not even experts in Kodshim.  (Yes I know the Temple Institute has people practicing the Avodah, which is really important, but that's only a part of it.)

Comment: Isn’t there a thing that Eliyahu can’t come on Erev Shabbos or Yom Tov since that means Mashiach would come on Shabbos or Yom Tov, which can’t happen?

Comment: If we are allowing for miracles then what are you unsure about?

Comment: @DoubleAA which miracles? To what extent?

Comment: Regarding the particular point of Yom Kippur - isn’t there a thing that Yom Kippur (and all the Yamim Tovim besides Purim) won’t exist in the future? So it’s a moot point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Rashi's opinion is that the third Holy Temple is already constructed (or is being constructed) in Heaven, and in the days of the Mashiach, it will descend onto the Temple Mount.<sup>1</sup> Therefore it will only take an instant to appear on the Temple Mount as it is prefabricated.

<sup>1. See his comments to Sukkah 41a and Rosh Hashanah 30a. Note that Rambam (Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Melachim 11:1, 4) and  others disagree with this, saying that the third Holy Temple will be built by men as the other two before it were built.</sup>

Comment: The third Beis Hamikdash is a huge step forwards.  But a lot more will have to be done to get it operational.  See my [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95507/can-we-get-the-beis-hamikdash-up-and-running-by-yom-kippur#comment315330_95507) on the question.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: @DoubleAA The OP asked: **With that, what type of miracles are to be expected with the building of the 3rd בית המקדש? Is there always a time when it can suddenly plop into existence...** I'm basically saying it _can_ "pop into existence" just like that, at least according to Rashi.

Comment: "...into existence, and be working without a hiccup, like it once was? Or is there going to be a startup sequence..."

Comment: +1 i think since tuma is hutra betzibbur for tumas meis and everyone is going to mikva on erev yomkippur to get rid of tumas keri that this is the right answer that on yom kippur we can appoint a Kohen Gadol assuming we will find his lost vestige and do the sacrifices!